# IF condition on a group of record using mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table t1 with two columns, Student_ID and Grade. The data shown like this;

```
Student_ID, Grade (1,'A'),(1,'C'),(1,'F'),(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(2,'A'),(2,'C'),(2,'A').
```

Now I have to group the Student_ID with a new column named 'Result'. Student_ID 1 have one grade 'F' so consider failed and Student_ID 2 have no 'F' grade so consider passed. Require result should be like this.

```
Student_ID     Result
    1          Failed
    2          Passed
```

Because the table have 500 records so can not manually enter 'Passed" or 'Failed'.

```
SELECT `Student_ID`, (IF(`Grade`='F',"Failed","Passed")) AS `Result`
FROM t1 group by `Student_ID`;
```

Above code will not work as the column `Grade` has 4 values not 1.

So code will be some thing like this.

```
SELECT `Student_ID`, (IF(`Grade` CONTAINS 'F',"Failed","Passed")) AS `Result` FROM t1 group by `Student_ID`;
```

There is no such thing CONTAINS in sql but may be HAVING or IN but how to use them here?

Comment: concat and then like should work, for example.

Comment: You tried using concat LIKE 'F%'

Comment: A MySQL IF uses `,` seperators and not `;`'s

Comment: `"Passed` needs a closing `"`

Comment: RiggsFolly! thank you for pointing out mistakes. I corrected as you advised. Actually I work usually on Libreoffice Base query and reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE statement with EXISTS:

```
select DISTINCT
  t.Student_ID,
  case 
    when exists (
      select 1 from t1 where Student_ID = t.Student_ID and Grade = 'F'
    ) then 'Failed'
    else 'Passed'
  end Result
from t1 t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7cLXSn7JDk5duaHD9Qm35z/0).
Results:

```
| Student_ID | Result |
| ---------- | ------ |
| 1          | Failed |
| 2          | Passed |
```

You can also do it by evaluating each `Grade` to `1` or `0` for `'F'` or `not 'F'` and then grouping by `Student_ID`:

```
select 
  t.Student_ID,
  case sum(t.Result) 
    when 0 then 'Passed'
    else 'Failed'
  end Result
from (select Student_ID, Grade = 'F' Result from t1) t
group by t.Student_ID
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7cLXSn7JDk5duaHD9Qm35z/2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both the solutions will work perfectly.

Comment: I am a new member on this forum and I really impressed on quick responses from members and specially the 'demo' with each solution. Thank you all and solute. I shall be proud to be a member of this community.